# Как работает "target" в "esbuild-loader"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Имеется лоадер

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
    loader: "esbuild-loader",
    options: {
      target: "es2018"
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  }]}
```

В "target" я пытался закинуть как "esnext" так и "es2015"

На выходе как я понял всегда получаю "es2015"

```
!function(){var e,t,n={679:function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(864),a={childContextTypes:!0,contextType:!0,contextTypes:!0,defaultProps:!0,displayName:!0,getDefaultProps:!0,getDerivedStateFromError:!0,getDerivedStateFromProps:!0,mixins:!0,propTypes:!0,type:!0},l={name:!0,length:!0,prototype:!0,caller:!0,callee:!0,
```

Как мне сбилдить в последней версии "esnext" ?

Comment: Таки, а что на входе и почему вы считаете что это не es2018?

Comment: Про target тут https://esbuild.github.io/api/#target

Comment: Я не спорю на счет es2018, просто интересно как сделать чтобы в билде у меня был es6+ синтакис без var и function?